# Сохранение и загрузка данных массива типа Class в localStorage

Tags: javascript, массивы, классы, localstorage

Итак, навоял я функцию, которая должна сохранять данные массива в localStorage (важный момент: данные в массиве представляют из себя классы):

```
// если в localStorage нет данных с ключом 'SAVEDECK', записываем туда наши данные с указанным ключом, в противном случае, сначала удаляем ранее сохраненные данные с этим ключом, а уже затем записываем туда новые данные
function SaveMyDeck(arr1) {
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('SAVEDECK') === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('SAVEDECK', JSON.stringify(arr1)); // запись
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('SAVEDECK'); // удаление
    localStorage.setItem('SAVEDECK', JSON.stringify(arr1)); // запись
  }
  console.log('Колода сохранена');
  console.log(arr1);
};
```

И вроде все работает, так как данные потом загружаются из localStorage:

```
// если localStorage содержит данные с ключом "SAVEDECK" - загружаем их в переменную SAVEDECK (которая должна быть типа массив)
if (localStorage.getItem("SAVEDECK")!= null) {
  console.log('Данные загружены');
  SAVEDECK = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SAVEDECK")); // чтение из localStorage и запись данных в переменную SAVEDECK
  console.log(SAVEDECK);
};
```

Вот только есть одна проблема: в консоли сохраненный и загруженный массив отображаются по разному:

Вот то, что сохраняется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот то, что загружается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, загружается уже не массив классов, а просто массив массивов. Итак вопрос: как мне это исправить? Чтобы конечный результат, был таким же, как и начальный.

Comment: в localStorage можно сохранять только сериализуемые данные

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне сохранить результат по другому, чтобы он не обнулялся каждый раз после обновления или закрытия/открытия страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SAVEDECK'))

if (localStorage.getItem("SAVEDECK")!= null) {
  console.log('Данные загружены');
  SAVEDECK = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SAVEDECK")).map((cardData) => {
    const { suits, attak, attaktipe, accuracy, health, defence, speed, dexterity } = cardData;  
    return new Cards(suits, attak, attaktipe, accuracy, health, defence, speed, dexterity);
  });
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение идеально подходит для решения поставленной задачи.