# Сохранение переменной в файл по клику на кнопку js

Tags: javascript, массивы, файлы, button, save

Итак проблема: есть у меня переменная типа массив, в которой хранятся данные типа класс. Но проблема в том, что после редактирования массива, новые данные сохраняются в нем лишь до первого обновления страницы. Итак, возник вопрос: как мне сохранить последний результат, чтобы при новой загрузке или обновлении страницы загружалось не значение по умолчанию, а то, чтобы было сохранено в массиве?

**Первый вариант**, который я додумался использовать - это localStorage. И все отлично работало за исключением того, что после загрузки мой массив преобразовывался из массива классов в массив массивов. Как мне подсказали на сайте, данный вариант для такого сохранения не годиться.

**Второй вариант**, до которого я додумался - это сохранить мою переменную в файл по нажатию одной кнопки, а затем просто загружать ее от туда по нажатию другой. Казалось бы тривильное решение и проблем возникнуть не должно. Но в итоге, у меня ничего не получилось, поэтому нужна ваша помощь.

Итак, я нашел код:

```
document.getElementsByTageName('a')[0].onclick =
  function() {
    var text = 'Hello';
    var csvData = 'data:application/txt;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    this.href = csvData;
    this.target = '_blank';
    this.download = 'txt.txt';
```

Которая отлично справляется с моей задачей. Но тут у меня пару моментов:

1. Я использую элемент не `а`, а `button` при этом у меня таких элементов много. Соответственно, как мне указать, на какую именно кнопку нужно реагировать? Я пробовал использовать `getElementsById`, но тогда консоль начала нещадно ругаться на то, что `getElementsById` не является функцией.
2. Кроме того, на данной кнопке у меня уже висит функция, которую нужно выполнить по клику. Отсюда второй вопрос: как подцепить на кнопку несколько функций для выполнения?

Вот так выглядит моя кнопка:

```
<button id="SAVE" onclick="SaveMyDeck(DECK_PL, SAVEDECK)"> SAVE DECK </button>
```

Вот так выглядит функция SaveMyDeck(DECK_PL, SAVEDECK):

```
function SaveMyDeck(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr2[i] = arr1[i];
  };
  SAVE(arr2);
  console.log('Колода сохранена');
  console.log(arr2);
```

Собственно я хотел бы, чтобы функция сохранения в файл продолжала функцию SaveMyDeck и сохраняла в файл значение `arr2` после того, как в нее будет скопировано значение `arr1`.

Я пытался оформить код выгрузки в файл отдельной функцией `SAVE`, а затем добавить эту функцию мою функцию `SaveMyDeck`, но это тоже не сработало. Тело функции `SAVE` выглядит так:

```
function SAVE(x) {
  var csvData = 'data:application/txt;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(x);
  this.href = csvData;
  this.target = '_blank';
  this.download = 'SAVE.txt';
};
```

Консоль ни на что не ругается, но и файл не выгружается.

Comment: _"... `getElementsById` не является функцией"_ Правильно, не является, ибо опечатка. Должно быть `getElementById`, так как предполагается, что ID уникален и является единственным на странице.

Comment: не пробовали сохранять в localStorage, а при парсинге данных оттуда классы заново создавать через конструктор?

Comment: @Aleksandr Belous, нет, так не пробовал... Как это организовать?

Comment: @drakoblack прикрепите в вопрос класс и как вы получаете данные из storage. В ответе исправлю

Comment: @Aleksandr Belous, добавил

Answer (score 0):

Не понял какая у вас там структура данных, но предположим что каждый элемент массива содержит данные для одной сущности.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SAVEDECK'))

if (localStorage.getItem("SAVEDECK")!= null) {
  console.log('Данные загружены');
  SAVEDECK = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SAVEDECK")).map((cardData) => {
    const { suits, attak, attaktipe, accuracy, health, defence, speed, dexterity } = cardData;  
    return new Cards(suits, attak, attaktipe, accuracy, health, defence, speed, dexterity);
  });
};
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в скобочках. `JSON.parse` должен вызываться до `.map()` а у вас `.map` вызывается внутри `JSON.parse`

Comment: да, поправил, спасибо

Comment: @Aleksandr Belous
Спасибо, сработало. Правда это не ответ на мой вопрос о сохранении данных в файл, но зато этот ответ идеально подходит для другого моего вопроса **[Сохранение и загрузка данных массива типа Class в localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369358/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-class-%d0%b2-localstorage)**